# During heroku installation, where can I put things in the file system?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to extract a repository (and I can't use a git submodule) into some location somewhere on the Heroku file system during the `preinstall` phase of a NodeJS deployment, but I can't find a permanent place where I have write access. Where can I write files during this phase that will be accessible to binary scripts I'll be running during runtime of the application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do what I want, after reading [they dyno docs on the ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) in the Cedar Stack.